cdkDragPlaceholder not working for horizontal Drag and Drop
I'm working on a website which involves horizontal drag and drop of elements.
I'm able to do horizontal drag and drop. But i need the user to identify where he actually dropping the elements. For that placeholder is needed.
I've checked the cdkDragPlaceholder which is completely working fine with vertical scrolling. But it's not working with horizontal scroll.
I even tried in stackblitz example from angular material documentation
Stackblitz Horizontal Drag and Drop
Here I've added the cdkDragPlaceholder  line in html
<div class="example-box" cdkDrag>
<div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="example-custom-placeholder">asd</div>
{{timePeriod}}

and I've added the below css block
  .example-custom-placeholder {
  background: #ccc;
  border: dotted 3px #999;
  min-height: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

But didn't got what I needed. Am i doing something wrong??
Can someone help me with this??

Change opacity of the placeholder
.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 1; // 0 => 1
}

